# How do I import all Google Chrome browser extensions to Vivaldi browser at once?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, chromium, vivaldi

I have been using a Google Chrome browser for a long time and also I used many extensions for productivity but now I switched to the Vivaldi browser because of some good features.

so I imported all my data like `saved password` and `search-history` and `bookmarks` from google chrome to Vivaldi browser from Vivaldi browser settings. but I can't find a way or setting to import all extensions from chrome to Vivaldi.

however, I searched this on google but can't find an easy solution.

so I want to import my all google chrome extensions to the Vivaldi browser at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be simpler just to find the extensions in the Chrome Store
manually and install them one by one.

You may find all your extensions in `chrome://extensions/`.
You can copy from there their names to the Chrome Store in Vivaldi
in order to find the extension.

If you enable "Developer mode" you will also see their runtime ID.
If you wish to directly access that extension in the Store, you may
use the URL `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ID`.

Comment: i was doing what you are telling here but still, I am looking for a very simple solution in a single click I want all extensions to Vivaldi from chrome

Comment: You may find all the extensions IDs in one list in `chrome://system/`. You could extract all the IDs into a file and use a text-editor to massage them into a list of URLs as in my answer. You may finally convert this into s batch script that will open all these pages in Chrome, so that all you have to do is click Install. However, I think this is too much work, unless you have dozens of extensions.

Comment: I will definitely go with your script solution so in the future I don't have the same problem thank you @harrymc